# Conditional If statements with decimal constraints

Tags: python, r, if-statement, nested-if

Say I have a condition that if a number ends with.00 add 2 to it and if a number ends with.99 add 3 to it. So if I had 5.00 and 5.99, I want to write a nested if statement that would allow me to add the right value to the original number based on its ending.

How to do that in R (or python)?

Comment: what do you mean by right value? so do you need 7.00 and 8.99 as your answer?

Comment: What form is your number in?  Note that if it's a float, your representation is not guaranteed to have the exact value that you expect.

Comment: @onyambu, by "right value" I meant adding the corresponding value, so either the 2 or the 3 based on the ending of the original number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to [floating point precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken), you will need to round your numbers to two decimals as values such as `5.99` cannot be represented exactly. This means a value such as `5.9921875` will have to fulfill your criterion as *finishing with 0.99*.

If you are fine with that, using [Python's Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) 
 will round implicitly and allow to extract the required decimals.

```
def get_decimals(num, n=2):
    return '{0:.2f}'.format(num)[-2:]

def func(num):
    decs = get_decimals(num)

    if decs == '00':
        return num + 2
    elif decs == '99':
        return num + 3
    else: return num
```

Comment: This is great, thank you. Any idea how i can do something similar in R?

Comment: @Oliver nice use of f strings

Comment: @Ef.O Unfortunately I have little if any knowledge of R.

Comment: @modesitt This is not actually using an f-string. I wanted to, but decided to keep it simple as it is not a feature commonly used yet.

Comment: No problem will figure it out. Thank you so much for your response, it's really helpful. - @OlivierMelançon

Answer (score 0):

In `python`.

```
def func(num):
    if round(num, 2) - int(num) < 0.001:
        return num + 2
    elif round(num, 2) - int(num) > 0.989:
        return num + 3 
    return num
```

You can round the number to 2 decimal places, subtract it's integer component, then round the result to check if it is *close to* `0.00` or `0.99`. Simply checking if the result before rounding is 0.00 or 0.99 is unreliable because of [`floating point numbers`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic).

Comment: Wouldn't you want to check against 0.005 instead of 0.001 and similarly for the second condition?

Comment: I think because the float is reasonable up to 12 digits, these boundaries are tighter but sufficient @OlivierMelançon

Comment: I toyed with your code and probably misread it at first because it actually works like a charm. Forget my previous comment

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are other values in your list/vector you need to deal with. I will give a vectorized format:

in R:

```
data = c(5.00,5.99,5.61)
mm = function(x){
  x = round(x,2)
  y = x-as.integer(x)
  ifelse(round(y-0.00,2)==0, x+2,ifelse(round(y-0.99,2)==0,x+3,x))
} 

mm(data)
[1] 7.00 8.99 5.61
```

In Python:  vectorized format with `numpy module`

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([5.00,5.99,5.61])
def mm(x):
    x = np.round(x,2)
    y = x - np.array(x,dtype = 'i')
    return np.where(np.round(y-0.00,2)==0, x+2,np.where(np.round(y-0.99,2)==0,x+3,x))

mm(x)
array([7.  , 8.99, 5.61])
```

Comment: I think Op is implying that the number should not be changed if the the number was 5.98 for example. my original solution did this too.

Comment: @modesitt what exactly do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

In `R` we can do

```
v1 + (floor(v1) != v1) + 2
#[1] 7.00 8.99
```

---

If we are looking for last two numeric elements

```
v2 <- sub(".*(.{2})$", "\\1", sprintf('%0.2f', v1))
ifelse(v2 == "00", v1 + 2, ifelse(v2 == "99", v1 + 3, v1))
#[1] 7.00 8.99
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c(5, 5.99)
```